# Webhooks functionality

Tags: webhooks, activecollab

I would like to 'export' data out of ActiveCollab into another 3rd party tool (Helix ALM), but I'm confused about how webhooks function.  Do webhooks execute a POST when changes are made in ActiveCollab, or are they executed by the 3rd party app and Activecollab returns the information that is requested in them?  I'm trying to understand if ActiveCollab is 'pushing' data when changes are made, or if the data is being requested by 3rd party app.  If AC is pushing data out, does it do so when ANY change is made or can it be configured to POST on specific/configurable changes?

I have reviewed the webhooks documentation but I'm unclear on the intended functionality.
https://activecollab.com/help/books/my-active-collab/webhooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveCollab sends out POST requests on relevant model events. These events are JSON encoded, and system will set `User-Agent` header to `Active Collab` when making a request.

No filtering for custom webhooks is currently available. You'll receive all webhooks, and you should filter them out on your end. Each webhook has `event_type` property set that you can use to find events that you are interested in.